# Does ENV['RAILS_ENV'] and ENV['RACK_ENV'] need to be set in staging and production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`ENV['RAILS_ENV']` and `ENV['RACK_ENV']` in development. returns `development`. In staging or production, it returns `nil`. Are we supposed to explicitly set these two environment variables for the staging and production environments?

Does Rails expect this to be set?

I also notice the following. I have this intializer: `config/initializers/01_redis.rb`:

```
redis_connection = Redis.new(host: URI.parse(ENV['REDIS_SERVER_URL']).host, port: URI.parse(ENV['REDIS_SERVER_URL']).port)
$redis           = Redis::Namespace.new(Rails.env.to_sym, redis: redis_connection)
```

When this file is inspected in staging. `Rails.env.to_sym` is interpreted as `:development`. Moreover, running `Rails.env` in Rails console, in staging, returns `staging`. Perhaps Rails needs `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` and `ENV['RACK_ENV']` prior to initializing the Rails app.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: if you are using linux, can you run `env` cmd and check if it's defined? in development.

Comment: @Nithin in OSX, running `env | grep ENV` returns nothing

Comment: not aware of `OSX` you must try `env | grep RAILS_ENV` . In ubuntu `.bashrc` is where I have used to set environment variables. You might want to have this fix on staging server.

Comment: Same result. Btw, `grep ENV` matches anything with `ENV`. Which means, if `RAILS_ENV` was defined in `env`, it would have shown. So does that mean I need to explicitly set these two `ENV` variables for staging and production?

Comment: oh I missed that, yep you are right ...

Comment: My thoughts are that there are many ways to specify these values, not just from environment variables. Rails and other scripts can look to see if the environment variable is defined and use it, but they might get it some other way... For example, you can set the environment in code or from the command line when starting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails needs to know what environment is it running on. The specific part of code can be found at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails.rb#L69

```
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

If you want to work in production mode, yes, you should set that environment variable.

However, some servers set the variable for you. For example, Apache Passenger, defaults to production and does exactly that.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerappenv